Problem with Angular Library integration with existing Application
I created an Angular (17.0.5) Library @myns/mylib , and added some component MyComponent to it.
@Component({
  selector: 'lib-my-component',
  template: `
    <p>
      core-ng works!
    </p>
  `,
  styles: [
  ]
})
export class MyComponent {

}

I Exported MyComponent in a Module
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    InputTextModule,
    InputTextareaModule,
    PasswordModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    MyComponent
  ]
})
export class MyLibModule { }



I also exported MyComponent in public-api.ts
export * from './lib/my-component.component';

Then I built the library (no issues), and linked it to another repo angular application (no issues so far) using npm link 
The library is well added to node_modules
I then imported my module
import {MyLibModule} from "@myns/mylib";
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent, NotfoundComponent],
    imports: [AppRoutingModule, AppLayoutModule, MyLibModule],
    providers: [
        {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy},
        CountryService, CustomerService, EventService, IconService, NodeService,
        PhotoService, ProductService
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {
}

and added a simple usage of the component in main app.component.html
<lib-my-component></lib-my-component>

When I try to build (ng build) I get this error
`
Error: src/app/..../app.component.html:66:17 - error NG8001: 'lib-my-component' is not a known element:

If 'lib-my-component' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
If 'lib-my-component' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
`
Le library seems to be understood by the compiler and the IDE (Idea) show no errors regarding the imports and the imported Module

Wasn't expecting making a simple library in angular so challenging.
Any clue ?
Tried to canonize the problem by trying the simplest form of it. Followed the existing tutorials.
At best i got that error. I suppose the problem is related to linking the library to the app, but I do not see it.
Tried all what I have found:
Checked names are well exported/imported
Changed linking through module name instead of path
Changed to prod mode with ("enableIvy": false)
but none got me closer than what I have reached so far.
I remarked as well that each time I do an
npm install

I need to redo my
npm link "path-to-lib-dist"


Intro
The main issue is lib-my-component isn't recognized in your application.
Try to use CommonModule in the imports:
imports: [
  CommonModule,
  FormsModule,
  InputTextModule,
  InputTextareaModule,
  PasswordModule,
],

In public-api.ts, make sure that you are exporting module and component:
export * from './lib/mylib.module';
export * from './lib/my-component.component';

Do link the Library:
cd dist/@myns/mylib
npm link
cd /path/to/your/application
npm link @myns/mylib

Add CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA in order to avoid schema errors:
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
  ...
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
})
export class AppModule {}

Give these a try and tell me how it goes!
References/Possible Extra Help
CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA added to NgModule.schemas still showing Error

For what concerns CommonModule, it is an angular base module, so yes it is already included. the component and the module are both exported in the library as said in the question. I tried linked against both lib name and lib path. and I tried as well adding CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA schema. It always fails
